# Using multiple contexts with one Migration History table

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a Database based on three different DB Contexts and would like to share the `__MigrationHistory` table between these. All the contexts are using schema. When The context generates its tables and the second starts, I get an error saying that `__MigrationHistory` table already exists in the DB. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is the code I am invoking to create the DB:

```
var context = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        context.TenantName = tenant;
        context.Database.Initialize(false); 

var ctx = IAssess.Models.SkillContext.CreateMe(tenant,  Tools.GetConnectionString());            
        ctx.Database.Initialize(false);
```

Comment: Witch version of EF you are using? Multiple contexts is only supported in EF 6.